# How do I fix the duplication names as well as the fixtures not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, node.js

itemName's are duplicated as well as issues with `cache` not updating the moment it runs the script, it updates the previous values from the last `item shop` sections,
If the `remove_duplicates` function isn't used it spams the same names atleast 5 times.

**Cache**

```json
{
  "Daily": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "DragonBall3B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "RepYourTeam3B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "RefereesB": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Referees2B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Referees3B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "LegendsofLightandDark1B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "LegendsofLightandDark2B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "DragonBall1B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "DragonBall2B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Featured": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Featured2": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "PatrickMahomes1B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "RepYourTeamB": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "RepYourTeam2B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z"
}
```

**Current Output:**

```yaml
• Daily (x1)
• DragonBall (x3)
• Featured (x2)
• LegendsofLightandDark (x2)
• PatrickMahomes (x1)
• Referees (x2)
• RefereesB (x1)
• RepYourTeam (x2)
• RepYourTeamB (x1)
```

**Expected Output**

```yaml
• Daily (x1)
• DragonBall (x3)
• Featured (x2)
• Legends of Light and Dark (x2)
• Patrick Mahomes (x1)
• Referees (x3)
• Rep Your Team (x3)
```

**Code**

```js
const niteStats = "https://api.nitestats.com/v1/epic/modes-smart";
const fortniteShop =
  "https://fortnitecontent-website-prod07.ol.epicgames.com/content/api/pages/fortnite-game/shop-sections";

const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require("fs");

const cache = JSON.parse(
  readFileSync(__dirname + "/../cache/cache.json", "utf8")
);

function remove_duplicates(arr) {
  var obj = {};
  var ret_arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj[arr[i]] = true;
  }
  for (var key in obj) {
    ret_arr.push(key);
  }
  return ret_arr;
}
const fixture1 = [
  "20",
  "19",
  "18",
  "17",
  "16",
  "15",
  "14",
  "13",
  "12",
  "11",
  "10",
  "9B",
  "8B",
  "7B",
  "6B",
  "5B",
  "4B",
  "3B",
  "2B",
  "1B",
  "9C",
  "8C",
  "7C",
  "6C",
  "5C",
  "4C",
  "3C",
  "2C",
  "1C",
];
const fixture2 = ["9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "B", "C"];

class UpcomingShop {
  constructor() {
    this.hmm = {};
  }
  async fetch_nitestats() {
    const res = await fetch(niteStats, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    return await res.json();
  }
  async fetch_epicGames() {
    const res = await fetch(fortniteShop, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    return await res.json();
  }
  async results() {
    let nitestats = await new UpcomingShop().fetch_nitestats();
    const sections =
      nitestats["channels"]["client-events"]["states"][0]["state"][
        "sectionStoreEnds"
      ];
    let epicgames = await new UpcomingShop().fetch_epicGames();

    let name;
    let sectionId;
    const items = [];
    //console.log(sections);
    if (cache !== sections) {
      for (var first in sections) {
        name = first;

        for (var second in epicgames) {
          name = first;
          sectionId = second["sectionId"];

          // console.log(name)
          if (name === sectionId) {
            try {
              name = second["sectionDisplayName"];

              // console.log(name)
            } catch {
              name = first;

              if (name.endsWith(fixture1)) {
                console.log(name + " BEFORE");
                name.slice(2);
                console.log(name + " AFTER");
              } else if (name.endsWith(fixture2)) {
                name.slice(2);
              }
            }
          }

          let data = JSON.stringify(sections, null, 2);

          writeFileSync(__dirname + "/../cache/cache.json", data, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(`${data} writen to cache`);
          });
          items.push(name);
        }
      }
      items.sort();
      let cleaned = remove_duplicates(items);
      const count = {};
      cleaned.forEach((str) => {
        const key = str.replace(/\d+.*/, "");
        count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
      });
      let val = Object.entries(count);
      let itemName;
      let itemNum;
      let result = [];
      for (var i in val) {
        itemName = val[i][0];
        itemNum = val[i][1];

        result += `• ${itemName} (x${itemNum})\n`;
      }
      return result;
    } else {
      const count = {};
      cache.forEach((str) => {
        const key = str.replace(/\d+.*/, "");
        count[key] = (count[key] || 0) + 1;
      });
      let val = Object.entries(count);
      let itemName;
      let itemNum;
      let result = [];
      for (var i in val) {
        itemName = val[i][0];
        itemNum = val[i][1];
        result += `• ${itemName} (x${itemNum})\n`;
      }
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }
  }
}
module.exports = new UpcomingShop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs to be more focused. Maybe this can help for the duplicate removals and grouping part.

Removal - compare after sorting removing common postfix if it matches [0-9A-Z] once or twice.

Grouping - using the `reduce` method.

```js
var input = {
  "Daily": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "DragonBall3B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "RepYourTeam3B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "RefereesB": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Referees2B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Referees3B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "LegendsofLightandDark1B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "LegendsofLightandDark2B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "DragonBall1B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "DragonBall2B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Featured": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "Featured2": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "PatrickMahomes1B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "RepYourTeamB": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z",
  "RepYourTeam2B": "2022-08-29T00:00:00Z"
}
const fixture1 = ["20", "19", "18", "17", "16", "15", "14", "13", "12", "11", "10", "9B", "8B", "7B", "6B", "5B", "4B", "3B", "2B", "1B", "9C", "8C", "7C", "6C", "5C", "4C", "3C", "2C", "1C"];
const fixture2 = ["9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "B", "C"];
var fixtures = [].concat(fixture1, fixture2);

function normalize(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < fixtures.length; i++) {
    if (str.endsWith(fixtures[i])) {
      return str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(fixtures[i]));
    }
  }
  return str;
}


var arr = Object.keys(input);
arr = arr.map(normalize);
var grouped = arr.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item] = (agg[item] || 0) + 1
  return agg;
}, {})
var result = Object.entries(grouped).map(function([key, value]) {
  return key + " (x" + value + ")";
})

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: Hey, question why does `PatrickMahomes1B` still show as `PatrickMahomes1B`?